# In linear regression, we have 0 training error if data dimension is high, but are there similar results for other supervised learning problems?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, machine-learning

I tried [posting this question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496855/in-linear-regression-we-have-0-training-error-if-data-dimension-is-high-but-ar) (the stack exchange for statistics) but didn't get an answer, so posting here:

Let's consider a supervised learning problem where $\{(x_1,y_1) \dots (x_n,y_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^p \times \mathbb{R}$ where $x_i \sim x$ are iid observations/samples, and $y_i \sim y$ are iid response variables. $y$ can be either continuous(regression) or discrete random variable (classification). *To simplify things*, you can treat the $x_i, y_i$'s below as individual input and output, as opposed to random vectors/variables.

We know that if the learning problem at hand is linear regression, then $p \ge n-1$ is sufficient to guarantee an interpolation - i.e. the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{p+1} $ *passing **through*** (and **not** passing **near**) all the points  $\{(x_1,y_1) \dots (x_n,y_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^p \times \mathbb{R}$, thereby giving us an exact **zero** training error (and **not** a *small, positive training error*).

**My question is:** are there such lower bound on the data dimension, a lower bound that's a function of the sample size $n,$ that ensures zero training errors when the supervised learning problem at hand is **not** a linear regression problem, but say a *classification problem*? To be more specific, assume that we're solving a logistic regression problem (or replace it by your favorite classification algorithm) with $n$ samples of dimension $p$. Now, irrespective of any distribution of the covariates/features, can we come up with a positive integer valued function $f$ so that $p \ge f(n)$ guarantees a perfect classification, i.e. zero training error (and **not**, small, positive training error)?

To be even more specific, let's consider the logistic regression, where given: $\{(x_1,y_1) \dots (x_n,y_n)\} \subset \mathbb{R}^p \times \{0,1\},$ one assumes: $$y_i|x_i \sim Ber(h_{\theta}(x_i)), h_{\theta}(x_i):= \sigma(\theta^{T}x_i), \sigma(z):= \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}},$$
and then finds the optimal parameter $\theta*$ of the model by:
$$\theta^{*}:= arg \hspace{1mm}max_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_iln(h_{\theta}(x_i)) + (1-y_i)ln (1 - h_{\theta}(x_i))$$

Is there a guarantee, just like linear regression, that when $p \ge f(n)$ for a certain positive integer-valued function $f,$ the training error is always zero, i.e. ${\theta^{*}}^{T}x_i>0$ when $y_i =1$ and ${\theta^{*}}^{T}x_i<0$ when  $y_i =0,$ irrespective of the distribution of $x_i?$ P.S. I understand that when $p$ is large enough, perhaps just $p=n+1,$ **there exists** $\theta_1\in \mathbb{R}^p$ so that ${\theta_1}^{T}x_i>0$ when $y_i =1$ and ${\theta_1}^{T}x_i<0$ when  $y_i =0,$ **but why does the same has to be true for $\theta^{*}?$**

The same question for other types of *regression problems*? I know the my question is broad, so some **links that goes over the mathematical details** will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\th\theta\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$In your logistic regression model, there is no function $f$ such that the condition $p\ge f(n)$ guarantees the zero training error.

Indeed, let us say that a point $x_i$ in your data is red if $y_i=1$ and blue of $y_i=0$. Let us say that $\th\in\R^p$ separates the red and blue points -- that is, has zero training error --- if $\th^Tx_i>0$ if $x_i$ is red and $\th^Tx_i<0$ if $x_i$ is blue.

Then, for any natural $p$, the zero training error cannot be attained by any $\th$ if e.g. (i) one of the $x_i$'s is $0$ or (ii) there are two red points of the form $u$ and $au$ for some real $a\ge0$ and some $u\in\R^p$ or (iii) there are two red points $u$ and $v$ and a blue point of the form $au+bv$ for some real $a,b\ge0$.

On the other hand, if the training data $\{(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)\}$ admits some $\th_*\in\R^p$ that separates the red and blue points (that is, has zero training error), then your formula
$$\th^*:= \text{arg max}_{\th\in\R^p}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i\ln h_{\th}(x_i)+(1-y_i)\ln(1-h_{\th}(x_i))$$
makes no sense, because then the supremum of
$$H(\th):=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i\ln h_{\th}(x_i)+(1-y_i)\ln(1-h_{\th}(x_i))$$
over all $\th\in\R^p$ is not attained. Rather, this supremum (equal $0$) is "attained" only in the limit, when $\th=t\th_*$, $t\to\infty$, and, as above, $\th_*\in\R^p$ separates the red and blue points (that is, has zero training error).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and observing that if $\theta^{*}\in \mathbb{R}^p$ does a perfect classification, then any positive multiple of $\theta^{*}$ does so as well and hence $H(\theta)$ doesn't have a maximum. I also well noted the three points you mentioned before when no $\theta$ can separate them. But for point (ii) did you mean that there's a red and a blue point of the form $u$ and $au, a\ge 0$ respectively (so that one of them will always get misclassified)?

But I wonder about this: if we change the signs of $y_i$ from $\{0,1\}$ to something else, say $\{a,b\},$ (contd)

Comment: (contd) then the classification problem won't change, but I wonder if we can still apply some modified version of the counterexamples (i)-(iii) you gave that heavily depends upon the fact that $y_i=0$ or $1.$ Of course this is my mistake, as I should've given general $y_i$'s. In fact as long as $y_i's$ take two different values, that still doesn't change the problem. But thanks to your counterexample, I do see the trouble with setting $y_i=0$ or $1.$

Comment: @Learningmath : I don't see any problem with how you label the $x_i$'s. Actually, and in my counterexamples I relabeled $1$ as red and $0$ as blue. However, in the expression for $H(\theta)$ we should keep the (standard) values $1$ and $0$ for the $y_i$'s, if we want to get meaningful results.